# PHP greek url convert

Tags: php, url, character-encoding

I have a URL like: domain.tld/Σχετικά_με_μας

[edit]
Reading the $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] I get to work with:

```
%CE%A3%CF%87%CE%B5%CF%84%CE%B9%CE%BA%CE%AC_%CE%BC%CE%B5_%CE%BC%CE%B1%CF%82
```

[/edit]

In PHP I need to convert it to HTML, I get pretty far with:

```
htmlentities(urldecode($navstring), ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
```

It results in:

```
&Sigma;&chi;&epsilon;&tau;&iota;&kappa;Î¬_&mu;&epsilon;_&mu;&alpha;&sigmaf;
```

but the 'ά' becomes 'Î¬' But I need it converted to

```
&#940;
```

I'dd really appreciate help. I need a universal solution, not a "string replace"

Comment: Sounds like a charset issue to me. And why do you need to use `htmlentities()`, do you do anything with that data, or is it just for displaying?

Comment: And what happens when you force the value to be UTF-8 like: htmlentities(utf8_encode($value)...

Comment: When read the server variables I get:
    %CE%A3%CF%87%CE%B5%CF%84%CE%B9%CE%BA%CE%AC_%CE%BC%CE%B5_%CE%BC%CE%B1%CF%82

that's why I need the urldecode

Comment: What does mb_detect_encoding($navstring) gives you ?

Comment: Elbarto, that gives me 'ASCII' (since it's percentages and letters and numbers..)

Comment: htmlentities(utf8_encode($navstring)) gives:
    %CE%A3%CF%87%CE%B5%CF%84%CE%B9%CE%BA%CE%AC_%CE%BC%CE%B5_%CE%BC%CE%B1%CF%82

(no change)

Comment: ok try to use mb_convert_encoding : http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-convert-encoding.php

Comment: Qirel, I have the value with &#940; in my mysql table where I need to match it with..

Comment: Elbarto, where would you sugest converting it to with mb_convert_encoding?

Comment: Well first try to do it with the $navstring alone before any other manipulation / convertion and check that you really have UTF-8 character encoding.

Comment: I have done: $navstring = mb_convert_encoding($navstring, 'UTF-8'); no change

Comment: I got `Σχετικά_με_μας` with header `Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have been playing around a little, and the following worked. Use mb-convert-encoding instead of htmlentities.:

```
mb_convert_encoding(urldecode($navstring),'HTML-ENTITIES','UTF-8');
//string(90) "domain.tld/&Sigma;&chi;&epsilon;&tau;&iota;&kappa;&#940;_&mu;&epsilon;_&mu;&alpha;&sigmaf;"
```

See [mb-convert-encoding](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-convert-encoding.php)

Answer (score 0):

## Information

All modern web browsers understand UTF-8 character encoding.
My advice would be :

- Always know the character encoding of the data you are using.
- Store your data with UTF-8.
- Output data with UTF-8

The mbstring php extension doesn't just manipulate Unicode strings. It also converts multibyte strings between various character encodings.
Use the mb_detect_encoding() [(ref)](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-detect-encoding.php) and mb_convert_encoding() [(ref 2)](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-convert-encoding.php) functions to convert Unicode strings from one character encoding to another.

## **PHP Needs to know !**

You also need to tell PHP that you are working with UTF-8, to tell him the default value, you can do it in your **php.ini file** :

```
default_charset = "UTF-8";
```

That default value is added to the default Content-Type header returned by PHP unless you specified it with the header() function :

```
header('Content-Type: application/json;charset=utf-8');
```

## Keep in mind

The default character set is used by a lot of functions in PHP such as :

- htmlentities()
- htmlspecialchars()
- all the mbstring functions
- ...